# How to hide and show table rows in XSL file according to the string returning null or not from JS file

Tags: javascript, xslt, if-statement, when-js

content is extracted from javascript function where enhanceddetails is declared and fetch in node type.I want condition when enhancedetails is nt selected and its returns null.. so its row will disappear.

### XSL file

```
<xsl:when test="selecteddata/essentialaddons[enhanceddetails!='']">
<fo:table-row background-color="white">
    <xsl:for-each select="selecteddata/enhancedaddons/enhanceddetails">
        <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid #cccccc">
            <xsl:for-each select="enhancedname">
                <fo:block text-align="justify" margin="10pt"  font-family="sans-serif">
                    <fo:inline padding-right="7pt" padding-left="10pt">
                        <fo:character character="&#x2022;"/>
                    </fo:inline>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </fo:block>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid #cccccc" padding-before="10%">
            <fo:block text-align="center" margin="5pt"  font-family="sans-serif">
                Fixed Fee
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
        <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid #cccccc" padding-before="7%">
            <fo:block text-align="center"  margin="5pt"  font-family="sans-serif">
                <xsl:value-of select="enhancedcost" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:for-each>
</fo:table-row>
```

Comment: you want to check if enhanceddetails != null or empty ??

Comment: No. Values are getting fetched but not getting displayed .I want to show the content of enhanceddetails if it is not empty or else hide that row when it is empty. Problem is i used various if/else.. xsl:when tags but it is not executing the output. I want proper method to hide or show according to logic

Comment: Can you provide xml file as input

Comment: <modules id="Additional"><module code="AS100" cost="10000" maximumhours="40" durationimpact="" name="Project Management" Description="hfgbhfd " type="electiveD" />
  <module code="AS101" cost="10000" maximumhours="40" durationimpact="" name="Technical Migration Services" Description="jhfgbh" type="electiveO"/>
  <module code="AS102" cost="10000" maximumhours="40" durationimpact="" name="Technical Integration Services" Description="jjvx" type="premium"/></module>

Comment: in above xml ..type is condition criteria... i will show u the value fetched in javascipt funtion .. from there the value is fetched.            var EnhancedDetails = EnhancedSelected[i].split("#;#");
                var strEnhancedName = EnhancedDetails[0];
                var strEnhancedCost = EnhancedDetails[1];
                var strEnhancedDescription = EnhancedDetails[2];

                var EnhancedDetailsNode = document.createElement("EnhancedDetails");
                var EnhancedName = document.createElement("EnhancedName");

Comment: in above comment Enhanceddetails is stored which contains sub-values enhancedname. if Enhanceddetails is empty. it should not get print in pdf which is created from XSL file.